# solving NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I have been studying Java since last week (I have basic knowledge in C#) and now I am practicing classes.
I don't understand why I get this exception, I tried to change the code many times and nothing works. This is the code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Competitor[] competitors;
        System.out.println("Enter number of competitors");
        competitors = Create(sc.nextInt());
        for(int i = 0;i<competitors.length - 1;i++)
            for(int j=i+1;j<competitors.length;j++)
                if(competitors[i].GetHeight()==competitors[j].GetHeight())
                    System.out.println(competitors[i]+" and "
                            +competitors[j] + "bounced to height"
                            +competitors[i].GetHeight());
    }
    static Competitor[] Create(int n) {
        Competitor[] competitors = new Competitor[n];
        for(Competitor c : competitors) {
            c = new Competitor();
            System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
            c.SetName(sc.next());
            c.SetId(sc.next());
            c.SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
        }
        return competitors;
    }
}
class Competitor {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private float height;
    public Competitor() {
    }
    public Competitor(String name, String id, float height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public String GetName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String GetId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public Float GetHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }
    public void SetName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void SetId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void SetHeight(Float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

I get the exception in this line:
if(competitors[i].GetHeight()==competitors[j].GetHeight())

What is the problem here?

Thanks very much!

Comment: How are you exiting the loop where you take the input? I compiled this and it just took input without stopping and never gave an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Create method initializes the competitors values in the wrong way. 
Try this:

```
    for(int i = 0;i<competitors.length;i++){
        competitors[i] = new Competitor();
        System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
        competitors[i].SetName(sc.next());
        competitors[i].SetId(sc.next());
        competitors[i].SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
    }
```

One more suggestion. While in C# methods name starts with one upper case char, in Java they start in lower case.

Comment: Thanks it works! But can you tell me why it didn't work? I just used the "improved for" that can be used for arrays (This is what I read in the book). And one more thing - now another thing doesn't work: if(competitors[i].GetHeight()==competitors[j].GetHeight()). 
It always false. Why is it?

Comment: It don't works because you're assigning the new Competitor value to a temporary variable c that the for-each loop creates for you.

It's like doing this:

`Competitor c = competitors[i];
 c = new Competitor();`

so you're assigning a new value to c but not to competitors[i].

Comment: Ok I understand now. I also solved the other problem, I just wrote in Competitor class in GetHeight method Float instead of float. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This enhanced for loop:

```
for(Competitor c : competitors) {
    c = new Competitor();
    System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
    c.SetName(sc.next());
    c.SetId(sc.next());
    c.SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
}
```

is  equivalent to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < competitors.length; i++) {
    Competitor c = competitors[i];
    c = new Competitor();
    System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
    c.SetName(sc.next());
    c.SetId(sc.next());
    c.SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
}
```

So you modified `c`, but you never modified `competitors`

---

Java have different conventions with C#. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Comment: But this is the syntax I read I have to use for enhanced for loop.
The enhanced for loop is actually useable only after allocating all the objects in the array?

Comment: @YuvalSimon Unfortunately, you just cannot use enhanced for loop everywhere. Such as this case.

Comment: Precisely, it is not intended for modifying the array, collection or whatever. Modification of objects that are already in the container is ok, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this

> ```
> Competitor[] competitors = new Competitor[n];
> for(Competitor c : competitors) {
>    c = new Competitor();
>    System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
>    c.SetName(sc.next());
>    c.SetId(sc.next());
>    c.SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
> }
> return competitors;
> ```

But like that you just assign a new Competitor to "c". You should take off that `c = new Competitor()` so it's like this

> ```
> Competitor[] competitors = new Competitor[n];
> for(Competitor c : competitors) {
>    System.out.println("Enter name, id and bounce height");
>    c.SetName(sc.next());
>    c.SetId(sc.next());
>    c.SetHeight(sc.nextFloat());
> }
> return competitors;
> ```

Your other problem with `SetHeight()` was because `SetHeight()` was picking a primitive value and putting it in a Class type Float (automatically thanks to [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)). The class type internally store the float primitive in a field. When you used ==, it compared the two objects and determined that they didn't point to the same place, even though their fields pointed to a float primitive with the same value.

That's why when comparing non-primitive types we should always use `.equals()` method instead of ==, unless you're trying to test it against null. `.equals()` will make sure it doesn't compare the place where the variable is pointing but their internal fields.

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/2576857

I think it will help you to understand both problems you had.